# How can I give the object the shape I want?

Tags: unity

I want to fit the net behind the goal but I don't know how to shape the net object? Example in the picture below (how can I give the shape I want to the black drawn place?);

[image]

Comment: Usually this would be done in a 3D Content Creation tool, like 3DS Max, Maya, Blender, etc. and then the resulting model file is imported into a game engine like Unity. Game engines typically don't have such rich 3D mesh editing tools built in, though you can find assets or write custom scripts to achieve some of those behaviours.

Comment: I will take into account what you have said. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I guess that's Unity.

Unity has a tool called **ProBuilder** that allows you to do basic modeling things. This tool has an option called *Probuilderize*, which basically converts meshes into editable models through ProBuilder. I've never used this option so I can't talk much about it, however I know it's there and I know it does that.

This is a simple task, so I don't see why not take advantage of what you have on hand. However, I would recommend solving these types of problems in dedicated software, such as Blender. But that is already out of the scope of this answer.

Comment: Thank you, I will try as soon as possible.